# WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

Basically, I tried to use `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and `devise` gem in my app.  However, when I try to do `rake db:migrate`, it keeps complaining about Cucumber.  The cucumber-rails is under `group :development, :test` in the Gemfile.

My gem environment:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.17
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
     - /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

After I ran `rake db:migrate` it gives me this message:

```
$ rake --trace db:migrate
WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb.  The rest of loading is being defered until env.rb is called.
  To avoid this warning, move 'gem cucumber-rails' under only group :test in your Gemfile
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant User
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:225:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:225:in `constantize'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise.rb:293:in `get'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise.rb:327:in `new'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise.rb:327:in `add_mapping'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:206:in `block in devise_for'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:205:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-2.0.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:205:in `devise_for'
/Users/user1/pachamama/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `instance_exec'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:272:in `eval_block'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:249:in `draw'
/Users/user1/pachamama/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:67:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/user1/pachamama/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:292:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user.rb wasn't created in app/models/ directory.  This resolve the error (uninitialized constant User).  The cucumber warning can be resolved by what Andrew suggested

```
gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
```

or

Make sure this exists `features/support/env.rb` in order to do that on my setup is the following:

```
rails g cucumber:install 
rails g cucumber:install capybara
rake cucumber
```

Answer (score 24):

Change the entry in your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
```

See these issues: [one](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/249), [two](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/pull/171).

Comment: I apologize, this will fix the warning you were getting, but not the "Uninitialized constant User" warning. That is completely different and separate and you really have two very disjoint questions.

Comment: The user.rb wasn't created in app/models/   This resolve the error (uninitialized constant User).  However, the "WARNING: Cucumber-rails required outside of env.rb." still there.

Comment: `gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false` Works for the cucumber warning.

Comment: Cheers - fixed the problem for me